# Best place for UI-related initialization code UITableViewCell with Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What is the best place for UI-related code that should be run on initialization for a `UITableViewCell` subclass? i.e.

```
self.someLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor DISBadgeRed];
self.anotherLabel.layer.cornerRadius = self.unseenMatchesLabel.frameHeight / 2;
```

**background**
Im using a storyboard so the designated initializer `- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` isn't called and in `initWithCoder:` which es called, UI isn't ready for these calls.

I could call this code from a method that is called within `cellForRow...` but then it would end up being called every time.

Comment: What about `awakeFromNib`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it in `awakeFromNib` and all the outlets and views from the Storyboard will be set up when its called.